# Inside jquery datatable binding multi select dropdown in each row

Tags: jquery, datatable, jquery-ui-multiselect

One of my jquery Datatable Column.(Using Chosen.Jquery.js)
Line No: 3 I have mentioned multiple class = "Chosen-Select" but it is not working.

```
           { "data": "Tagss",
           "render": function (d, t, r) {
            var $select = $('<select multiple class="chosen-select</select>', 
                               {
                                    "id": r[0] + "start",
                                    "value": d
                                });

                                var items = "";
                             $.each(d, function (i, item) {
                                    var $option = $("<option></option>", {
                                        "text": item.PageName,
                                        "value": item.pageTagId
                                    });
                                    if (d == item) {
                                        $option.attr("selected", "selected")
                                    }
                                    $select.append($option);
                                });
                                return $select.prop("outerHTML");

                                //return $select.prop('selected', true).trigger('change');


                            }

                        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , you have missing double quote in you class while applying.

secondly apply css after html is rendered. Because your control is not getting css and not properly applying.